# What is a chain in PyMC3?

Tags: python, bayesian, markov-chains, pymc3

I am learning PyMC3 for Bayesian modeling. You can create a model and sample with:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymc3 as pm

# obs is a DataFrame with a single column, containing
# the observed values for variable height
obs = pd.DataFrame(...)

# we create a pymc3 model
with pm.Model() as m:
    mu = pm.Normal('mu', mu=178, sd=20)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower=0, upper=50)
    height = pm.Normal('height', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=obs)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000)

pm.traceplot(trace)
```

[image: pymc3 output]

When I check the `trace` (in this case 1000 samples from the posterior probability), I notice that 2 chains are created:

```
>>> trace.nchains
2
```

I read the tutorial on PyMC3 and looked through the API but it is unclear to me what a chain represents (in this case I asked for 1000 samples from the posterior but I got 2 chains, each one with 1000 samples from the posterior).

Are the chains different runs of the sampler with the same parameters or do they have some other meaning/purpose?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A chain is a single run of MCMC.  So if you have six 2-d parameters in your model and ask for 1000 samples, you will get six 2x1000 arrays for *each* chain.

When running MCMC, it is a best practice to use multiple chains, as they can help diagnose problems. For example, the [Gelman-Rubin diagnostic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99375/gelman-and-rubin-convergence-diagnostic-how-to-generalise-to-work-with-vectors) requires multiple chains, and runs automatically (using `joblib`, which tries to use multiple cores if possible) if you use more than 1 chain in `PyMC3`.

As a concrete example of when you might want multiple chains, consider sampling from a multimodal distribution. Even the `NUTS` sampler may not visit both modes in a single chain, but you could diagnose this using multiple chains.

[image: multiple chains]

Note that `PyMC3` usually combines the chains when you work with them (e.g., using `trace.get_values('my_var')`), since they are all valid MCMC samples.  This does lead to some confusing behavior in that asking for 1000 samples actually gets you 4000 on most systems, where you get 4 chains by default.